# Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL in sql 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016

Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL" error message is getting when MERGE statement is used in SQL server. This is a known issue in SQL 2008 nad in SQL 2012. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2671078)

Can anyone have idea whether it is fixed in SQL 2016?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question here.  Are you getting a "You cannot set a non-nullable column to null" error when you are sure that you are not trying to do so?

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this issue today and the problem came down to a broken index on the column I was attempting to display. I had a join on a company ID column that was common to both tables. I was attempting to display the company name from the company master table joined to the invoice table. 
I received this error:
Msg 681, Level 16, State 3, Line 12
Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL.
I queried both tables for a NULL company ID and there were none. I queried the company table for NULL company names and there were none. If I removed the column company name from the query, it worked. On the company master table there was an index for the company name column. 
I used the estimated execution plan to see that the broken query was using the company name index on the company master table. Since that column was not in the working query I started looking at the indexes. 
I tried to rebuild them all and the company name index failed to rebuild with the error:
Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL.
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 681)

To resolve, I dropped and recreated the index.